# Access a domain controller without a DNS server

Tags: windows, windows-7

I have a Windows 7 workstation that is joined to an Active Directory domain controlled by a Windows 2012 R2 server.  The workstation was set up locally and joined to the domain locally.

I moved the workstation to a remote location controlled by someone else.  They required me to use their DNS and I was not allowed to enter my own DNS into the workstation (my domain controller is also a DNS server).  There is a VPN from this remote location to my domain controller, I can ping the domain controller and verified that ports are open.  EDIT:  This is a router/firewall based VPN that is always on, not a VPN client.

I tried editing the hosts file on the computer, but I am still not able to log in as users who do not have cached credentials.

```
AD/DNS server name:  DCPRIMARY
Domain name:  mydomain.local
```

In the hosts file, I have:

```
192.168.55.5     DCPRIMARY
192.168.55.5     DCPRIMARY.mydomain.local
192.168.55.5     mydomain.local
192.168.55.5     mydomain
```

When I try to logon, I get this error:

```
There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.
```

For testing, they allowed me to put in 192.168.55.5 as the primary DNS, and I was able to log as a domain user at that point (although it took 5 minutes to login).  I was told I need to come up with a different solution besides using my DNS as the primary DNS.  They will not allow any changes to their DNS server.

How can I point this workstation to a domain controller without using a DNS server?  It will always have that static IP and is the only domain controller this workstation will ever see.

Alternately, they will allow me to enter my DNS into the "Alternate DNS Server", but my understanding is the computer will only use that if the Primary DNS is offline.  Is there any way to have the computer use the Alternate DNS if the Primary DNS does not return a match?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the VPN is not up before the login. I would use a VPN client that support a prelogin login.

Install a client like OpenVPN as a service, and allow it to connect before the login.

I suggest [Always On VPN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-access/vpn/vpn-device-tunnel-config) if you can upgrade the workstation to a Windows 10 build 1709+, as the remote endpoint can be a cisco asa or such, no need to be RRAS server specifically.

For your alternate DNS's problem I would make the VPN route all traffic if you can, thus becoming the default route 0.0.0.0, any IP and DNS received by the VPN client will be the default's one, bypassing your local area network card configuration for all the traffic.

Comment: I am not using a VPN client, it's an always-on VPN from their router/firewall to my router/firewall.

Comment: @user70624 You should had wrote it, but why they dont put a condional forwarder for your domain inside their DNS ?

Comment: Sorry about that, I use hardware based VPNs most of the time, I forget that's not the norm.  They are incredibly strict about what they allow on their network, they are a very large organization and don't want to make changes that could potentially affect others.  It was an effort just to get the VPN open to my domain controller.

Answer (score 1):

If you can establish a VPN to your domain, the best solution would almost certainly be to connect to the VPN via IP, or hard code the name/ip of your VPN into your hosts file.  Then set your client to use the IP of the Domain controller, via the VPN.  This would require that your VPN be always on, and configured to operate system wide though.

The more complex, but flexible option would be to use the name resolution policy table on your client.  This allows you to specify servers to use for a specific zone on the client.  It is a bit of a pain to manage though.

Here ix a rule for `*.example.org` that would some servers for resolution.  In your case, you would have to establish the VPN first, then provide the add a rule to your table for the IP of your DC via the VPN.

```
$Rule = @{
    'Namespace'   = '.example.org'
    'Comment'     = 'the domain'
    'NameServers' = ('2001:db8:a362:58::2', '2001:db8:a362:58::3')
}
Add-DnsClientNrptRule @Rule
```

Comment: This is a hardware based VPN on their router and my router, not a VPN client.

Comment: Sure seems like that would have been an important detail to put in your question.  Maybe you could spend some time and edit it and actually describe how things are setup?  Like if you have a hardware-based why would you need to configure anything on your workstation related to the local network...

Comment: My apologies, I use hardware based VPNs most of the time and I forget this is not the norm.  The location where I have the workstation is not a network I control, and they require me to use their DNS as the primary DNS because that's the only way to get through their web proxy.  They also won't allow any changes in their DNS.  However, in order to use AD authentication (which I require for the system on my workstation to work) it seems as though the DNS needs to be aware of the AD domain controller.  I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place.

Comment: I just don't understand though.  If your hardware-based VPN has established a VPN, why would anything happening on the local network matter at all?  Just send everything through the VPN, including dns/http/https/etc.  If the VPN is unable to establish a tunnel because of firewall on the network, then fix the hardware VPN.

Comment: Because just because I have a hardware-based VPN doesn't mean all network traffic goes through it.  Because the DNS server I am connected to is on the local network (not through the VPN) that dictates what hostnames I can lookup.  My default gateway is also on their network, not through the VPN.  The only reason the VPN is there is to provide access to my domain controller.